# Proof on approximating adiabatic evolution by quantum circuit

Tags: adiabatic-model

I am reading on how the adiabatic evolution can be approximated by a quantum circuit of size poly(nT) and I am trying to follow the derivation in the paper

> W. van Dam, M. Mosca, and U. Vazirani, “How Powerful is Adiabatic
>   Quantum Computation?,” Proceedings 2001 IEEE International Conference
>   on Cluster Computing, pp. 279–287, 2001.

In section 4, page 4, it states that:

"The Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff theorem tells us how well we can approximate ‘parallel Hamiltonians’ by consecutive
ones: $|||\exp(A+B) − \exp(A)\exp(B)||| \in O(|||AB|||)$."

The norm I believe is just the operator induced norm. I am familiar with the BCH formula but could not see the above relation directly coming out from the formula. **So how is this relation derived?**

I tried looking into the reference which is "matrix analysis" by Rajendra Bhatia but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 3):

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula says that you can expand
$$
\log(e^Ae^B)=A+B+[A,B]/2+\ldots=M
$$
where higher order terms have 3 or more uses of $A$ and $B$. Now, let's say that $A$ and $B$ are anti-Hermitian so that $e^A$, and similar terms, are unitary. We have
$$
\|\exp(A+B)-\exp(A)\exp(B)\|=\|e^{A+B}\left(\mathbb{I}-e^Me^{-(A+B)}\right)\|.
$$
The matrix norm is invariant under the action of unitaries, so this is the same as
$$
\|\mathbb{I}-e^Me^{-(A+B)}\|.
$$
Now, you might apply the BCH formula again to get
$$
\|\mathbb{I}-e^{M-A-B-[M,A+B]/2+\ldots}\|,
$$
the point being that the leading order $A+B$ stuff cancels from $M-A-B$ and the commutator, leaving terms like $[A,B]$. If both $A$ and $B$ are small ($O(\epsilon)$), then higher order terms have vanishing relevance, so we have
$$
\|\mathbb{I}-e^{[A,B]/2+O(\epsilon^3)}\|,
$$
and if we do an expansion on that, we get
$$
\|\mathbb{I}-(\mathbb{I}+[A,B]/2+O(\epsilon^3))\|=\|[A,B]\|/2+O(\epsilon^3)=O(\|AB\|).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder in the of quantum annealing,(A and B are i times the starting and end hamiltonian of annealing respectively), **whether we can assume A and B are actually small**.

Comment: Your original question was about the *simulation* of an adiabatic quantum computation. When doing that, the thing that you're simulating is $\cos\theta A+\sin\theta B$, and you're probably trying to build it out of $A$ and $B$. You break this evolution down into lots of tiny steps of size $\epsilon$. If each step can be achieved to $O(\epsilon^2)$, you can achieve the overall evolution of $O(\epsilon)$.

Comment: Do you mean that because each time step is small, so each of the A and B are also small, so we can disregard the higher power terms?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.